# How can i apply jquery to this web form?

Tags: jquery

I've just started working with Jquery- find it very cool and easy. I have a small project that I would like to apply jquery to, but my code has just gotten ugly and long so am seeking help in to the following:

onload of this form I want to hide all the subsections, then when you select **Flyer** from the **Type** dropdown the **Flyer** fieldset section should appear. When you select **Banner** from the **Type** dropdown the **Banner** fieldset section should appear and all others disappear.

Now in the **banner** **fieldset**, if you select  "**Size 1**" **checkbox**, the Size 1 - Details fieldset should appear and so on.

Could someone show me the cleanest, efficient way of accomplishing this with jquery?

```
<form action="" method="post">
<fieldset name="fs_mainInfo">
                <legend>Main Info</legend>

                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 255px"><label id="Label1">First Name</label></td>
                        <td><input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 255px">Last Name</td>
                        <td><input id="lname" name="lname" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 255px"><label id="Label2">Type</label></td>
                        <td><select id="jobType" name="jobType">
                        <option value="Flyer">Flyer</option>
                        <option value="Banner">Banner</option>
                        <option value="Postcard">Postcard</option>
                        </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 255px">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </fieldset>
            <fieldset name="fs_flyer" id="fs_flyer">
                <legend style="color:blue">Flyer</legend>
                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 188px"><label id="Label1">Sizes:</label></td>
                        <td><input id="flyerSize[]" name="flyerSize[]" type="checkbox" value="Size 1" />Size 1<br/>
                        <input id="flyerSize[]"  name="flyerSize[]" type="checkbox" value="Size 2"  />Size 2<br/>
                        <input id="flyerSize[]"  name="flyerSize[]" type="checkbox" value="Size 3"  />Size 3<br/>
                                                </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </fieldset>
<fieldset name="fs_banner" id="fs_banner">
                <legend   style="color:blue">Banner</legend>
                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 188px"><label id="lblBannerSize">Sizes:</label></td>
                        <td><input id="bannerSize[]" name="bannerSize[]" type="checkbox" value="Size 1" />Size 1<br/>
                        <input id="bannerSize[]"  name="bannerSize[]" type="checkbox" value="Size 2"  />Size 2<br/>
                        <input id="bannerSize[]"  name="bannerSize[]" type="checkbox" value="Size 3"  />Size 3<br/>
                                                </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </fieldset>

<fieldset name="fs_postcard" id="fs_postcard">
                <legend  style="color:blue">Postcard</legend>
                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 188px"><label id="lblPostcardSize">Sizes:</label></td>
                        <td><input id="postcardSize[]" name="postcardSize[]" type="checkbox" value="Size 1" />Size 1<br/>
                        <input id="postcardSize[]"  name="postcardSize[]" type="checkbox" value="Size 2"  />Size 2<br/>
                        <input id="postcardSize[]"  name="postcardSize[]" type="checkbox" value="Size 3"  />Size 3<br/>
                                                </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </fieldset>

<fieldset name="fs_flyer_desc1" id="fs_flyer_desc1">
                <legend  style="color:maroon">Size 1 - Details</legend>
                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 188px"><label id="lblFlyerDescription">Description:</label></td>
                        <td><textarea name="TextArea1" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </fieldset>
            <fieldset name="fs_flyer_desc2" id="fs_flyer_desc2">
                <legend  style="color:maroon">Size 2 - Details</legend>
                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 188px"><label id="lblFlyerDescription2">Description:</label></td>
                        <td><textarea name="sizeOneDesc2" id="sizeOneDesc2" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </fieldset>
            <fieldset name="fs_flyer_desc3" id="fs_flyer_desc3">
                <legend style="color:maroon">Size 3 - Details</legend>
                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 188px"><label id="lblFlyerDescription3">Description:</label></td>
                        <td><textarea name="sizeOneDesc3" id="sizeOneDesc3" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing your markup a bit so that it contains a bit more metadata, I've mocked up a quick answer to your question.

Primarily, I added classes `fs-size` and `fs-type` to the fieldsets containing fields concerning with the size and type, respectively. It allows you to quickly reference them as a group in a CSS selector -- e.g. `$('.fs-size').hide()`

Then, I changed values in your `<input/>` and `<select/>` elements to reflect the real values you use (`value="1"` rather than `value="Size 1"` will save us the need to do parsing when we need to use the selected value to choose which `<fieldset/>` to show.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<fieldset name="fs_mainInfo">
                <legend>Main Info</legend>

                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 255px"><label id="Label1">First Name</label></td>
                        <td><input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 255px">Last Name</td>
                        <td><input id="lname" name="lname" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 255px"><label id="Label2">Type</label></td>
                        <td><select id="jobType" name="jobType">
                        <option value="flyer">Flyer</option>
                        <option value="banner">Banner</option>
                        <option value="postcard">Postcard</option>
                        </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 255px">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </fieldset>
            <fieldset name="fs_flyer" id="fs_flyer" class="fs-type">
                <legend style="color:blue">Flyer</legend>
                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 188px"><label id="Label1">Sizes:</label></td>
                        <td><input id="flyerSize[]" name="flyerSize[]" type="checkbox" value="1"   class="input-size"/>Size 1<br/>
                        <input id="flyerSize[]"  name="flyerSize[]" type="checkbox" value="2"   class="input-size" />Size 2<br/>
                        <input id="flyerSize[]"  name="flyerSize[]" type="checkbox" value="3"   class="input-size" />Size 3<br/>
                                                </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </fieldset>
<fieldset name="fs_banner" id="fs_banner" class="fs-type">
                <legend   style="color:blue">Banner</legend>
                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 188px"><label id="lblBannerSize">Sizes:</label></td>
                        <td><input id="bannerSize[]" name="bannerSize[]" type="checkbox" value="1"  class="input-size" />Size 1<br/>
                        <input id="bannerSize[]"  name="bannerSize[]" type="checkbox" value="2"  class="input-size" />Size 2<br/>
                        <input id="bannerSize[]"  name="bannerSize[]" type="checkbox" value="3" class="input-size" />Size 3<br/>
                                                </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </fieldset>

<fieldset name="fs_postcard" id="fs_postcard" class="fs-type">
                <legend  style="color:blue">Postcard</legend>
                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 188px"><label id="lblPostcardSize">Sizes:</label></td>
                        <td><input id="postcardSize[]" name="postcardSize[]" type="checkbox" value="1" class="input-size"/>Size 1<br/>
                        <input id="postcardSize[]"  name="postcardSize[]" type="checkbox" value="2"   class="input-size"/>Size 2<br/>
                        <input id="postcardSize[]"  name="postcardSize[]" type="checkbox" value="3"  class="input-size" />Size 3<br/>
                                                </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </fieldset>

<fieldset name="fs_flyer_desc1" id="fs_flyer_desc1"  class="fs-size">
                <legend  style="color:maroon">Size 1 - Details</legend>
                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 188px"><label id="lblFlyerDescription">Description:</label></td>
                        <td><textarea name="TextArea1" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </fieldset>
            <fieldset name="fs_flyer_desc2" id="fs_flyer_desc2"  class="fs-size">
                <legend  style="color:maroon">Size 2 - Details</legend>
                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 188px"><label id="lblFlyerDescription2">Description:</label></td>
                        <td><textarea name="sizeOneDesc2" id="sizeOneDesc2" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </fieldset>
            <fieldset name="fs_flyer_desc3" id="fs_flyer_desc3"  class="fs-size">
                <legend style="color:maroon">Size 3 - Details</legend>
                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 188px"><label id="lblFlyerDescription3">Description:</label></td>
                        <td><textarea name="sizeOneDesc3" id="sizeOneDesc3" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </fieldset>
</form>​​​​​​​​​
```

Then the code becomes pretty straightforward, except for the bit I commented.

```
$('#jobType').change(function() {
    $('.fs-type').hide();
    $('#fs_' + this.value).show();

    // this was a bit tricky for me at first
    // hide all sizes and show only sizes previously selected
    // for this type
    $('.fs-size').hide();
    $('#fs_' + this.value + ' .input-size:checked').each(function(i, el) {
        $('#fs_flyer_desc' + el.value).show();
    });
});
$('.input-size').change(function() {
    var el = $('#fs_flyer_desc' + this.value);
    if (this.checked) {
      el.show();    
    }
    else {
      el.hide();    
    }
});
$('#jobType').change();
$('.fs-size').hide();
​
```

The code hides all fields initially (the second-to-last line invokes the change event to achieve this, showing only the default selected option) and then shows only what was selected.

This commented bit checks which checkboxes are checked inside the appropriate `.fs-type` fieldsets and resets which `.fs-size` fieldsets are displayed accordingly.

I would add as a comment that since the only thing that is different between three `.fs-type` fieldsets is the title, you could have only one fieldset and simply change the caption, e.g.

```
$('#jobType').change(function() { $('.fs-type legend').html($(this).html()); });
```

All code (except for the last line above) is available in thie fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YC7Xe/

**Edit**: I added the demo for my last comment here: http://jsfiddle.net/YC7Xe/1/ . It also declares two functions `updateType()` and `updateSize()` so as to reduce code duplication.

Comment: This is really well done, the issue is "class" is already being used for all the fields in the actual web app, so i have to use either the name, id which are all like this: 1506[], 3403[], etc.  When I try to swap out the class and use the name, I get "unrecognized expression" error.

Comment: You can have multiple classes, e.g. `class="one-class another-class"`. You can actually also prepare this in advance with `$('#fs_flyer_desc1, #fs_flyer_desc2, #fs_flyer_desc3').addClass('fs-size')`. What gives you an error?

Comment: Yaval - first let me say the code below works perfectly, but ran into a snag - the fieldsets may not follow a particular naming convention such as fs_flyer1, fs_flyer2, etc. Could be something completely different & out of left field, so I need the " $("input[name='flyerSize[]']:checked").each(function(i, el) {" part of your code, but also, I need to be able to say: if the value of one of the boxes checked = 1 >> $('#fs_moonStart').show(), if value of boxes checked is 1 and 2 >> $('#fs_moonStart').show();$('#fs_moonStart').show(); and so on.  How can do accomplish this?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Is this the same question as above? Perhaps it's better to write up a new one (or search for an existing answer)?

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#jobType").change(function() {

      $("#fs_flyer, #fs_banner, #fs_postcard").hide();

       if ( $("#jobType").val() == "Flyer") {
           $("#fs_flyer").show();               

        } else if ( $("#jobType").val() == "Banner") {
              $("#fs_banner").show();

        }  else if ( $("#jobType").val() == "Postcard") {
              $("#fs_postcard").show();

        }      
 });
});
```